# Gazebo version 6: Symbol not found : __ZTVN4Ogre7MeshPtrE

Tags: ogre, dyld, rpath

I'm currently trying to run an old version of Gazebo as it is a part of a toolkit I need to use. When I try to run gzserver, I get the following output

```
$ gzserver
dyld: Symbol not found: __ZTVN4Ogre7MeshPtrE
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libgazebo_skyx.6.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/libgazebo_skyx.6.dylib
fish: 'gzserver' terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
```

Running otool on gzserver

```
⋊> ~ otool -L /usr/local/bin/gzserver                                                                                                                                                               13:00:44
/usr/local/bin/gzserver:
    libgazebo.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    libgazebo_sensors.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    libgazebo_rendering.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    /usr/local/opt/freeimage/lib/libfreeimage.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.18.0)
    /usr/local/opt/tbb/lib/libtbb.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.200.5)
    libgazebo_physics.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    libgazebo_util.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    libgazebo_physics_ode.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    libgazebo_ode.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    libgazebo_gimpact.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    libgazebo_opende_ou.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    /usr/local/opt/libccd/lib/libccd.2.dylib (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 2.0.0)
    libgazebo_opcode.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    libgazebo_physics_simbody.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    /usr/local/opt/simbody/lib/libSimTKsimbody.3.6.dylib (compatibility version 3.6.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/simbody/lib/libSimTKmath.3.6.dylib (compatibility version 3.6.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/simbody/lib/libSimTKcommon.3.6.dylib (compatibility version 3.6.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 4.0.0)
    libgazebo_physics_bullet.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    /usr/local/opt/bullet/lib/libBulletSoftBody.2.87.dylib (compatibility version 2.87.0, current version 2.87.0)
    /usr/local/opt/bullet/lib/libBulletDynamics.2.87.dylib (compatibility version 2.87.0, current version 2.87.0)
    /usr/local/opt/bullet/lib/libBulletCollision.2.87.dylib (compatibility version 2.87.0, current version 2.87.0)
    /usr/local/opt/bullet/lib/libLinearMath.2.87.dylib (compatibility version 2.87.0, current version 2.87.0)
    /usr/local/opt/ogre1.9/lib/libOgreRTShaderSystem.1.9.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.9.0, current version 1.9.0)
    /usr/local/opt/ogre1.9/lib/libOgreMain.1.9.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.9.0, current version 1.9.0)
    /usr/local/opt/ogre1.9/lib/libOgreTerrain.1.9.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.9.0, current version 1.9.0)
    /usr/local/opt/ogre1.9/lib/libOgrePaging.1.9.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.9.0, current version 1.9.0)
    /usr/local/opt/ogre1.9/lib/libOgreOverlay.1.9.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.9.0, current version 1.9.0)
    libgazebo_transport.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    libgazebo_skyx.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    libgazebo_selection_buffer.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    libgazebo_msgs.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    libgazebo_common.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    /usr/local/opt/tinyxml/lib/libtinyxml.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavcodec.58.dylib (compatibility version 58.0.0, current version 58.18.100)
    /usr/local/opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavformat.58.dylib (compatibility version 58.0.0, current version 58.12.100)
    /usr/local/opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavutil.56.dylib (compatibility version 56.0.0, current version 56.14.100)
    /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 9.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/ffmpeg/lib/libswscale.5.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.1.100)
    /usr/local/opt/libtar/lib/libtar.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/sdformat3/lib/libsdformat.3.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.7.0)
    /usr/local/opt/gts/lib/libgts-0.7.5.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.1.0)
    /usr/local/opt/glib/lib/libgthread-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 5801.0.0, current version 5801.1.0)
    /usr/local/opt/glib/lib/libgmodule-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 5801.0.0, current version 5801.1.0)
    /usr/local/opt/glib/lib/libglib-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 5801.0.0, current version 5801.1.0)
    /usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.5.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework/Versions/A/OpenAL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/gdal/lib/libgdal.20.dylib (compatibility version 25.0.0, current version 25.1.0)
    /usr/local/opt/protobuf/lib/libprotobuf.17.dylib (compatibility version 18.0.0, current version 18.0.0)
    libgazebo_math.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    /usr/local/opt/ignition-math2/lib/libignition-math2.2.dylib (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 2.9.0)
    /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/libboost_thread-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/libboost_signals-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/libboost_system-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/libboost_regex-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/libboost_iostreams-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/libboost_date_time-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/libboost_chrono-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/libboost_atomic-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 400.9.4)
```

When I try to run otool on the file gzserver is complaining about, I get

```
$ otool -L /usr/local/lib/libgazebo_skyx.6.dylib                                                                                                                                
/usr/local/lib/libgazebo_skyx.6.dylib:
    libgazebo_skyx.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    /usr/local/opt/ogre1.9/lib/libOgreMain.1.9.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.9.0, current version 1.9.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.200.5)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 400.9.4)
```

I already tried to run the building of gazebo(which is installed from a git repo) several times and reinstall ogre. I installed qt4 using Homebrew.

When I am running gazebo, I get the following error

```
$ gazebo
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libQtGui.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/gazebo
  Reason: image not found
fish: 'gazebo' terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
```

If I'm running otool on gazebo

```
otool -L /usr/local/bin/gazebo                                                                                                                                                                 13:00:51
/usr/local/bin/gazebo:
    libgazebo.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    libgazebo_sensors.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    libgazebo_gui.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    libgazebo_physics.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    libgazebo_physics_ode.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    libgazebo_ode.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    libgazebo_gimpact.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    libgazebo_opende_ou.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    /usr/local/opt/libccd/lib/libccd.2.dylib (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 2.0.0)
    libgazebo_opcode.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    libgazebo_physics_bullet.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    /usr/local/opt/bullet/lib/libBulletSoftBody.2.87.dylib (compatibility version 2.87.0, current version 2.87.0)
    /usr/local/opt/bullet/lib/libBulletDynamics.2.87.dylib (compatibility version 2.87.0, current version 2.87.0)
    /usr/local/opt/bullet/lib/libBulletCollision.2.87.dylib (compatibility version 2.87.0, current version 2.87.0)
    /usr/local/opt/bullet/lib/libLinearMath.2.87.dylib (compatibility version 2.87.0, current version 2.87.0)
    libgazebo_physics_simbody.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    /usr/local/opt/simbody/lib/libSimTKsimbody.3.6.dylib (compatibility version 3.6.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/simbody/lib/libSimTKmath.3.6.dylib (compatibility version 3.6.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/simbody/lib/libSimTKcommon.3.6.dylib (compatibility version 3.6.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 4.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.200.5)
    /usr/local/opt/ogre1.9/lib/libOgreRTShaderSystem.1.9.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.9.0, current version 1.9.0)
    /usr/local/opt/ogre1.9/lib/libOgreMain.1.9.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.9.0, current version 1.9.0)
    /usr/local/opt/ogre1.9/lib/libOgreTerrain.1.9.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.9.0, current version 1.9.0)
    /usr/local/opt/ogre1.9/lib/libOgrePaging.1.9.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.9.0, current version 1.9.0)
    /usr/local/opt/ogre1.9/lib/libOgreOverlay.1.9.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.9.0, current version 1.9.0)
    libgazebo_client.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    libgazebo_util.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    libgazebo_gui_building.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    libgazebo_gui_model.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    libgazebo_gui_viewers.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    libgazebo_rendering.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    libgazebo_transport.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    libgazebo_skyx.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    libgazebo_selection_buffer.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    libgazebo_msgs.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    libgazebo_common.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    /usr/local/opt/freeimage/lib/libfreeimage.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.18.0)
    /usr/local/opt/tinyxml/lib/libtinyxml.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavcodec.58.dylib (compatibility version 58.0.0, current version 58.18.100)
    /usr/local/opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavformat.58.dylib (compatibility version 58.0.0, current version 58.12.100)
    /usr/local/opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavutil.56.dylib (compatibility version 56.0.0, current version 56.14.100)
    /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 9.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/ffmpeg/lib/libswscale.5.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.1.100)
    /usr/local/opt/libtar/lib/libtar.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/tbb/lib/libtbb.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/sdformat3/lib/libsdformat.3.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.7.0)
    /usr/local/opt/gts/lib/libgts-0.7.5.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.1.0)
    /usr/local/opt/glib/lib/libgthread-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 5801.0.0, current version 5801.1.0)
    /usr/local/opt/glib/lib/libgmodule-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 5801.0.0, current version 5801.1.0)
    /usr/local/opt/glib/lib/libglib-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 5801.0.0, current version 5801.1.0)
    /usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.5.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework/Versions/A/OpenAL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/gdal/lib/libgdal.20.dylib (compatibility version 25.0.0, current version 25.1.0)
    libgazebo_math.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.5.1)
    /usr/local/opt/ignition-math2/lib/libignition-math2.2.dylib (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 2.9.0)
    /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/libboost_thread-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/libboost_signals-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/libboost_system-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/libboost_regex-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/libboost_iostreams-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/libboost_date_time-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/libboost_chrono-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/libboost_atomic-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/protobuf/lib/libprotobuf.17.dylib (compatibility version 18.0.0, current version 18.0.0)
    @rpath/libQtGui.4.dylib (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.7)
    @rpath/libQtCore.4.dylib (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.7)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 400.9.4)
```

I'm using fish as my shell and my operating system is OSX.

When I'm running cmake(before running gzserver and gazebo) I get the following output:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" \                                                                                                                       13:18:16
                                               -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
                                               -DENABLE_SSE4=True \
                                               -DENABLE_TESTS_COMPILATION:BOOL=False
-- Gazebo version 6.5.1
-- High memory tests: enabled
--

====== Finding 3rd Party Packages ======
-- Operating system is Apple MacOS X
-- Checking for module 'freeimage>=3.9.0'
--   No package 'freeimage' found
--   freeimage.pc not found, trying freeimage_include_dir and freeimage_library_dir flags.
--   Found /usr/local/include/FreeImage.h
--   Looking for FreeImage.h - found
--   Looking for libfreeimage - found
-- HDF5: Using hdf5 compiler wrapper to determine C configuration
-- HDF5 Found
-- Checking for module 'libprofiler'
--   No package 'libprofiler' found
-- Looking for libprofiler - not found
-- Checking for module 'libtcmalloc'
--   No package 'libtcmalloc' found
-- Looking for libtcmalloc - not found
-- Looking for DARTCore - not found
--  DART not found, for dart physics engine option, please install libdart-core4-dev.
-- Using system tinyxml.
-- Looking for libtar.h - found
-- Looking for libtar.so - found
-- Checking for module 'tbb'
--   No package 'tbb' found
-- TBB not found, attempting to detect manually
-- Checking for module 'OGRE-Overlay'
--   Found OGRE-Overlay, version 1.9.0
-- Checking for modules 'playercore>=3.0;playerc++;playerwkb'
--   No package 'playercore' found
--   No package 'playerc++' found
--   No package 'playerwkb' found
--  Player not found, gazebo plugin for player will not be built.
-- Looking for GTS - found
-- Looking for libusb-1.0 - found. USB peripherals support enabled.
-- Checking for module 'OculusVR'
--   No package 'OculusVR' found
--  Oculus Rift support will be disabled.
-- Boost version: 1.67.0
-- Looking for SDFormat - found
-- Boost version: 1.67.0
-- Boost version: 1.67.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
--   signals
--   system
--   filesystem
--   program_options
--   regex
--   iostreams
--   date_time
--   chrono
--   atomic
-- Looking for dlfcn.h - found
-- Looking for libdl - found
-- Looking for libgdal - found
--  ronn not found, manpages won't be generated
-- Looking for gzip to generate manpages - found
-- Looking for libspnav and spnav.h - not found
-- Looking for uuid - found
-- Checking for module 'libgvc'
--   No package 'libgvc' found
-- Checking for module 'libcgraph'
--   No package 'libcgraph' found
-- Checking for module 'libcdt'
--   No package 'libcdt' found
-- Could not find graphviz headers.
-- Could NOT find Graphviz_Gvc (missing: GRAPHVIZ_GVC_LIBRARY)
-- Could NOT find Graphviz_Cgraph (missing: GRAPHVIZ_CGRAPH_LIBRARY)
-- Could NOT find Graphviz_Cdt (missing: GRAPHVIZ_CDT_LIBRARY)
-- Could NOT find Graphviz Headers (missing: GRAPHVIZ_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Looking for libgraphviz-dev - not found
--  Graphviz not found, Model editor's schematic view will be disabled.
-- Looking for ignition-math2-config.cmake - found
-- ----------------------------------------

-- Looking for display capabilities
--  + found a display available ($DISPLAY is set)
--  + found a valid dri display (glxinfo)
-- Checking gazebo build type
-- Enable host CFlags
--
SSE4 will be enabled if system supports it.

-- Enable upstream CFlags
--

====== Configuring 3rd Party Packages ======
-- ----------------------------------------

-- BUILD WARNINGS
--  DART not found, for dart physics engine option, please install libdart-core4-dev.
--  Player not found, gazebo plugin for player will not be built.
--  Oculus Rift support will be disabled.
--  ronn not found, manpages won't be generated
--  Graphviz not found, Model editor's schematic view will be disabled.
-- END BUILD WARNINGS

-- Custom CFlags: -stdlib=libc++  -Wall -Wextra -Wno-long-long -Wno-unused-value -Wno-unused-value -Wno-unused-value -Wno-unused-value -Wfloat-equal -Wshadow -Winit-self -Wswitch-default -Wmissing-include-dirs -pedantic -std=c++11
-- Build Type: Release
-- Install path: /usr/local
-- Configuration successful. Type make to compile gazebo
-- Configuring done
CMake Warning:
  Value of common_headers contained a newline; truncating


CMake Warning:
  Value of gui_headers contained a newline; truncating


CMake Warning:
  Value of math_headers contained a newline; truncating


CMake Warning:
  Value of message_headers contained a newline; truncating


CMake Warning:
  Value of physics_headers contained a newline; truncating


CMake Warning:
  Value of rendering_headers contained a newline; truncating


CMake Warning:
  Value of sensors_headers contained a newline; truncating


CMake Warning:
  Value of transport_headers contained a newline; truncating


CMake Warning:
  Value of util_headers contained a newline; truncating


CMake Warning (dev):
  Policy CMP0042 is not set: MACOSX_RPATH is enabled by default.  Run "cmake
  --help-policy CMP0042" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy command to
  set the policy and suppress this warning.

  MACOSX_RPATH is not specified for the following targets:

   ActuatorPlugin
   ArrangePlugin
   BreakableJointPlugin
   BuoyancyPlugin
   CameraPlugin
   CartDemoPlugin
   CessnaGUIPlugin
   CessnaPlugin
   ContactPlugin
   DepthCameraPlugin
   DiffDrivePlugin
   ElevatorPlugin
   ExceptionModelPluginConstructor
   ExceptionModelPluginInit
   ExceptionModelPluginLoad
   ForceTorqueModelRemovalTestPlugin
   ForceTorquePlugin
   GpuRayPlugin
   ImuSensorPlugin
   InitialVelocityPlugin
   Issue1208Plugin
   JointTrajectoryPlugin
   LiftDragPlugin
   ModelPropShop
   ModelTrajectoryTestPlugin
   MudPlugin
   PressurePlugin
   RandomVelocityPlugin
   RayPlugin
   RaySensorNoisePlugin
   RestUiPlugin
   RestWebPlugin
   RubblePlugin
   SimEventsPlugin
   SkidSteerDrivePlugin
   SonarPlugin
   SphereAtlasDemoPlugin
   SpringTestPlugin
   TimerGUIPlugin
   TransporterPlugin
   VehiclePlugin
   gazebo_common
   gazebo_gimpact
   gazebo_gui
   gazebo_gui_building
   gazebo_gui_model
   gazebo_gui_viewers
   gazebo_math
   gazebo_msgs
   gazebo_ode
   gazebo_opcode
   gazebo_opende_ou
   gazebo_physics
   gazebo_physics_bullet
   gazebo_physics_ode
   gazebo_physics_simbody
   gazebo_rendering
   gazebo_rendering_deferred
   gazebo_selection_buffer
   gazebo_sensors
   gazebo_skyx
   gazebo_transport
   gazebo_util
   libgazebo
   libgazebo_client

This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
  Value of common_headers contained a newline; truncating


CMake Warning:
  Value of gui_headers contained a newline; truncating


CMake Warning:
  Value of math_headers contained a newline; truncating


CMake Warning:
  Value of message_headers contained a newline; truncating


CMake Warning:
  Value of physics_headers contained a newline; truncating


CMake Warning:
  Value of rendering_headers contained a newline; truncating


CMake Warning:
  Value of sensors_headers contained a newline; truncating


CMake Warning:
  Value of transport_headers contained a newline; truncating


CMake Warning:
  Value of util_headers contained a newline; truncating


-- Build files have been written to: /Users/malinaandahl/projects/revolve-simulator/gazebo/build
```